# Is there any limit of issuing passes using a PassType ID Certificate?

Tags: passbook

We have requirement to create Event passes. Once a Passtype ID certificate is created, is there any limit on signing of passes using PassType ID Certificate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no limit to the number of passes that can be created for a single PassID Certificate.

However, the certificate plays a significant role in how passes are grouped together in a users's Passbook.

If you anticipate issuing passes for multiple events and your users will hold multiple passes for different events, then you may wish to consider using a separate certificate for each event, to prevent passes for different events being stacked on top of one another.